# Mat_Open is not working while using matio in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, matio

I am using the matio library to write the contents of a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>` and some other data to a MatLab file. I used a tutorial here: http://na-wiki.csc.kth.se/mediawiki/index.php/MatIO

However, `Mat_Open` stays `NULL`, meaning I can't write anything to the file. There are no error messages, linking/compilation is fine, `Saving mat file` is never printed and the exit code of the program is `0`. Am I missing something obvious?

Contents of the function that should create the MatLab file:

```
mat_t *mat;
matvar_t *matvar;
unsigned long dims[3] = {100, 100, 3};
unsigned long single_dim[1] = {1};
unsigned long size = 100;
double number = 3.14;

mat = Mat_Open("/home/ruben/data.mat", MAT_ACC_RDWR);

if(mat != NULL) {
    std::cout << "Saving mat file" << std::endl;
    matvar = Mat_VarCreate("matrix", MAT_C_DOUBLE, MAT_T_DOUBLE, 3, dims, matrix, 0);
    Mat_VarWrite(mat, matvar, MAT_COMPRESSION_ZLIB);
    Mat_VarFree(matvar);

    matvar = Mat_VarCreate("number", MAT_C_DOUBLE, MAT_T_DOUBLE, 1, single_dim, &number, 0);
    Mat_VarWrite(mat, matvar, MAT_COMPRESSION_ZLIB);
    Mat_VarFree(matvar);

    Mat_Close(mat);
}
```

I include the library using `#include <matio.h>`, and link it with `-std=c++11 -L/usr/lib -lmatio -lz`. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I found the project on GitHub, submitted this as an issue: https://github.com/tbeu/matio/issues/45

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself, with some help of the author of the project.
Two things were going wrong:

1. If the MatLab file doesn't exist yet, one should use `Mat_Create` or `Mat_CreateVer`.
2. `std::vector` elements cannot be simply used as arguments to the `Mat_VarCreate` function. A pointer to the first element should be passed instead.

Updated working code:

```
mat_t *mat;
matvar_t *matvar;
unsigned long dims[3] = {100, 100, 3};
unsigned long single_dim[1] = {1};
unsigned long size = 100;
double number = 3.14;

mat = Mat_Create("/home/ruben/data.mat", NULL);

if(mat != NULL) {
    std::cout << "Saving mat file" << std::endl;
    matvar = Mat_VarCreate("matrix", MAT_C_DOUBLE, MAT_T_DOUBLE, 3, dims, &matrix->at(0), 0);
    Mat_VarWrite(mat, matvar, MAT_COMPRESSION_ZLIB);
    Mat_VarFree(matvar);

    matvar = Mat_VarCreate("number", MAT_C_DOUBLE, MAT_T_DOUBLE, 1, single_dim, &number, 0);
    Mat_VarWrite(mat, matvar, MAT_COMPRESSION_ZLIB);
    Mat_VarFree(matvar);

    Mat_Close(mat);
}
```

Hope this will be useful to someone.